# How can draft post after 1 year

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I need to do this in my post in custom post type, I need when to day publish new post. After 1 year from today convert post status from publish to draft.

How can do that ?

Comment: This is very possible, and I believe that this has been answered before. What have you actually tried yourself and where did you fail. It is much easier to help you if you can share your code and explain where you have failed please file an [edit] and add all relevant info **inside** your post

Comment: i dont have any code for this so i am here to get steps to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code (maybe working) , but i'am not sure cause not testing :

```
function amin_show_expire(){
  global $wpdb;
  $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'CUSTOM' AND post_status = 'publish'");
  if( !empty($result)) foreach ($result as $a){
      $show_time = get_the_time("Y-m-d", $a->ID );
      $show_time=date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 years", strtotime($show_time)));
      if ( $show_time < date("Y-m-d")){//compare 1 year after post with current time
          $my_post = array();
          $my_post['ID'] = $a->ID;
          $my_post['post_status'] = 'draft';
          wp_update_post( $my_post );
      }
  } // end foreach
}

add_action( 'init', 'amin_show_expire' );
```

Comment: i add it in `function.php` and show me this error 
`WordPress database error: [Table 'cartan.wp_posts' doesn't exist] SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'serve' AND post_status = 'publish'`

Comment: @Android-wd -> Open phpmyadmin and see what posts table's name is ?
for example rt_posts,wp_posts and etc. (depend to prefix name like wp,rt and so on)

Comment: That is a very expensive operation to run.